# How to get list of students who have enrolled atleast once and then final status is not enrolled?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've following table, It has log of students who enrolled and enrolled out datewise.

```
student_id | is_enrolled | created_at
-------------------------------------
1          | 1           | 2020-01-01
2          | 0           | 2020-01-02
3          | 0           | 2020-01-01
1          | 0           | 2020-01-02
4          | 1           | 2020-01-02
1          | 0           | 2020-01-03
3          | 0           | 2020-01-03
4          | 1           | 2020-01-04
```

If you see, the student 1 has enrolled on `2020-01-01` and then enrolled out on `2020-01-02`. Student 2 and 3 have never enrolled. Student 4 enrolled multiple times but never enrolled out. Hence, not in the output.

Basically, I want to write a query whose output is students like `1`, who have atleast enrolled once and final status is not enrolled. I was able to get all the enrolled students, but stuck after that point.

My queries,

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id 
  FROM student 
 WHERE is_enrolled = 1 
 ORDER
    BY student_id; # gives me 1 and 4
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5336d/1)

Ideally, a single query solution without nested query would be awesome. I'm, okay with multiple query solution as well.

**Note:** I was able to get the required output by using for-loops in my code, but I would like to learn can I do this just by SQL queries. I'm not looking for any programming language code.

Comment: What MySQL version you have, because since MySQL 8.0 added helpful window function

Comment: I'm on v5.7. Can you share more information on window function and how can I use it? We might migrate to v8 by end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM student x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT student_id
            , MAX(created_at) created_at
         FROM student
        GROUP
           BY student_id
     ) y
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id
   AND y.created_at = x.created_at
  JOIN student z
    ON z.student_id = x.student_id
   AND z.is_enrolled = 1
 WHERE x.is_enrolled = 0;
```

As an aside, never use `SELECT *`, and in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate.

Comment: this gives me output 2 and 3, which is kinda opposite of what I was looking for. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sure. I understand about group by clause. I edited the question :)

Comment: @Abhishek Clearly, you don't!!

Comment: Can it be done without using nested query? Or there is no way to do it?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? And what's wrong with a subquery?

Comment: I'm using MySQL v5.7. Well, internally nested query makes 2 queries isn't?

Comment: For 5.7, this version will be fastest (on a properly indexed data set).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DBA ( database expert ), but I'll normally use something like this for my MSSQL database:

```
WITH summary AS (
SELECT 
  student_id, 
  is_enrolled, 
  created_at
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.student_id ORDER BY s.created_at DESC) AS rk
  FROM student s)
SELECT s.*
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk = 1
AND is_enrolled = 1
```

What I did was adding an extra column after the order by is done, you want to see if the latest created value has an is_enrolled value of 1.

The "With" part is used to define a sub query, with some extra logic in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggreation:

```
select student_id
from student s
group by student_id
having sum(is_enrolled) >= 1 and
       max(created_at) = max(case when is_enrolled = 0 then created_at end);
```

The first condition checks that the student is enrolled at least once.

The second checks that the latest `created_at` is the latest `created_at` for an unenrolled record.  That checks that the last status is "unenrolled".

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5336d/12) is the SQL Fiddle.